# Backbone js events internally calling query

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Iam practising Backbone JS these days. Actually I have some doubt regarding when exactly `add` and `reset` events are triggering in the below code.

Iam actually practising this code: `http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2012/09/13/backbone-js-for-absolute-beginners-getting-started-part-2/`

**Here is the code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<section id="todoapp">
    <header id="header">
        <h1>Todos</h1>
        <input id="new-todo" placeholder="what needs to be done?" />
    </header>
    <section id="main">
        <ul id="todo-list"></ul>
    </section>
</section>

<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
  <div class="view">
    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">
    <label><%- description %></label>
  </div>
</script>


<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var app = {};

app.Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        description: '',
        status:'incomplete'
    }
});


app.TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Todo,
    url:'api/todos'
})
app.todoList = new app.TodoList();


app.TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
})

app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#todoapp',
    initialize: function(){
        this.input = this.$('#new-todo');

        this.listenTo(app.todoList,'add',this.addOne);
        this.listenTo(app.todoList,'sync',this.addAll);
        app.todoList.fetch();
    },
    events: {
        'keypress #new-todo': 'createTodoOnEnter'
    },
    addAll: function(){
        this.$('todo-list').html('');
        app.todoList.forEach(this.addOne,this);
    },
    addOne: function(todo){
        var view = new app.TodoView({model:todo});
        $('#todo-list').append(view.render().el);
    },
    createTodoOnEnter: function(e){
        if ( e.which !== 13 || !this.input.val().trim() ) { // ENTER_KEY = 13
          return;
        }
        app.todoList.create(this.newAttributes());
    },
    newAttributes: function(){
        return{
            description: this.input.val().trim(),
            status: 'incomplete'
        }
    }
});

var appView = new app.AppView();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Scenario 1:**
If I Comment `add` event in the below code, Refresh the page and Nothing is displayed on the page. Why and How?? whats going on internally?

```
//  this.listenTo(app.todoList,'add',this.addOne);
    this.listenTo(app.todoList,'reset',this.addAll);
    app.todoList.fetch();
```

**Scenario 2:**
If I Comment `reset` event in the below code, Refresh the page and I can see my server data on the page. Why and How?? whats going on internally?

```
    this.listenTo(app.todoList,'add',this.addOne);
//  this.listenTo(app.todoList,'reset',this.addAll);
    app.todoList.fetch();
```

In the same way as above, please replace `reset` with `sync` and output will be bit different again. I will be glad if some tries my above code and check the output yourself and then please explain me how events are calling internally. I already checked with Backbonejs.org documentation regarding these events but still I am having confusion on these events calling behavior.

Comment: this didn't help ? http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

Comment: @Deeptechtons : HI, Actually I read the link which you provided too.. But I will be glad if you could able to explain bit in detail how events internally calling..

Comment: FYI: `reset` and `sync` are not the same event. `sync` is fired when you syncing collection with server, whereas `reset` is only fired when `reset` method is called. So you cannot use `reset` instead of `sync` and vice versa.

Comment: it will help if you put this within a jsfiddle